# Certificate Authority installation doesn't work

Tags: certificates, import

I've seen many many posts* lined to my problem, although none of them seems to refer to my bug.
I set up my small PKI (for Web, mail etc.) and now try to import my CA .crt file to my Android device. Each time I try to open the cert file I am prompted for entering a name for the imported CA. I then validate the name and the purpose (VPN and applications) and a small Pop-up appears "MyCA has been imported."
However, when I go to `Preferences > Security > Trusted certificates > User certificates`, my CA doesn't appear.

I tried to download it :

- via Web (URL pointing directly to the .crt file encoded in PEM)
- with the file (uploaded to `Downloads/` folder, then `Import from SD > Internal`, same behavior)
- via ADB to the added-certs/ folder (access restrictions indeed)

Does someone have an idea ?

My phone :
Android 5.1.1
OxygenOS 2.1.2
OnePlus X

Thanks !

*[Unable to Install Certificate](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97893/unable-to-install-certificate)

*[How do I install a user certificate?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57976/how-do-i-install-a-user-certificate)

*http://androidforums.com/threads/cant-install-security-certificate.668968/

*[How do you import CA certificates onto an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/how-do-you-import-ca-certificates-onto-an-android-phone)

Comment: OnePlus ticket : #494797